# ngx-datatable - select events not registering

Tags: angular, typescript, accessibility, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to make my Angular/Typescript website ADA compliant, including allowing items to be selected via keyboard. Sadly, all I can figure out is a mouse click.

I've tried various combinations of events, but I must be missing something.

```html
<ngx-datatable-column[width]="50" [resizeable]="false" [sortable]="true" [draggable]="false" [canAutoResize="false">
    <ng-templatelet-row="row"ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <strong></strong>
    <div[class.datatable-icon-right]="!row.$$expanded"
        [class.datatable-icon-down]="row.$$expanded"
        title="Expand/Collapse Row"
        (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to get the click event on the arrow to accommodate an enter keypress or something similar?

Comment: Does your piece of your code work? `(click)="toggleExpandRow(row)"` this code looks ok. Or you want to click in another place?

Comment: @StepUp I was looking to also add keypresses. I did figure it out though.The solution was to make the inner div an anchor that would register the keypress properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Angular, so I can't provide the exact syntax, but I do know that click events are passed as a keypress "enter" natively on anchor and button elements, but not on divs. Try providing an equivalent keypress handler, and if the event has the key code of enter, then run toggleExpandRow(row). You'll need to add a tabindex="0" attribute to allow keyboard-only users to place focus on the element, and provide a role="button" attribute as well, to describe that this isn't an inactive div.

It should look something like this:

```
div[class.datatable-icon-right]="!row.$$expanded"
        [class.datatable-icon-down]="row.$$expanded"
        title="Expand/Collapse Row"
        tabindex="0"
        role="button"
        (keypress)="handleKeypress($event, toggleExpandRow)"
        (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)">
    </div>
```

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thanks @Taylor N I had tried that, but I did figure it out though.The solution was to make the inner div an anchor that would register the keypress properly.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a special syntax for keyboard events. [You can use `(keyup.enter)` or `(blur)` events:](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter)

```
<input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">
<p>{{value}}</p>
```

Comment: This put me on the right track!  The solution was to make the inner div an anchor that would register the keypress properly.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! The solution was to make the inner div an anchor that would register the keypress properly. Thanks to @StepUp for getting me on the right track and a random ngx-datatables commentator on a site I can no longer find!